# Windows 8 Blog Reader Tutorial NullPointerException

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I was following the Microsoft Windows Blog Reader example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj676792.aspx).

Half way through I got a NullPointerException so I thought I might have not followed the tutorial correctly.

They also provide the completed code so I copied this and created a new project and when I went to run it I got the same NullPointerException.

I find it hard to believe that Microsoft would have a tutorial with errors in it so I'm wondering is it just me?

If there is a problem is there anywhere where the completed code can be found?

This is the line that causes the exception but it's not the only one.

```
var matches = _feedDataSource.Feeds.Where((feed) => feed.Title.Equals(title));
```

Comment: What is `null` here? Is it `_feedDataSource`, is it `_feedDataSource.Feeds`, is it `feed`, is it `feed.Title` or is it `title`?

Comment: feed is null. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/fdff773b-6a26-4a3c-93c1-4e84f4eb93ec shows how to fix the Exception but then there is another Exception later on in the code.

Comment: It *is* a miserable tutorial.  I walked away from it when I found it to only exercise typing skills.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you recommend any other tutorial instead?

Comment: No.  There's a large amount of sample code available that shows how bits and pieces of WinRT are used.  I found them to be worthwhile.  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Hans, you may be better off grabbing one of the samples available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps.

One nice thing about accessing the samples at the above site is that the code for each sample can be browsed online, so you can get a sense before downloading it if the sample is right for your needs.

But another cool trick is that you can also get these apps using the New Project dialog in Visual Studio 2012. Just use File > New Project, and look for the Online section in the left-hand pane (see below):

[image: New Project Dialog]

Once you're in the online section for the language of your choice, you can use the search box at the top right to filter for the feature for which you want a sample. I use this regularly to learn about new features as I prepare to implement them.

For more info on developing Windows Store apps, check out [Generation App](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Answer (score 1):

For the past few days, i was working on another app: **Channel9 Blog Reader**.
It's same as the **Windows 8 Blog Reader**, the main difference being the feed links changed from "*windowsteamblog.com*" or "*blogs.windows.com*" to "*channel9.msdn.com*".

And also there are a couple of minor changes as it is a Windows 8.1 app & not Windows 8 app, so it will be better if u read this article about *migrating a Windows 8 app to Windows 8.1 app* :-
[migrating a Win 8 app to Win 8.1 app](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/05/managing-your-app-on-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/)

Here is the link to the source code of the app :-
[Channel9 Blog Reader App Source Code](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=685D07B09AF813E2&id=685D07B09AF813E2!1170)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the feed links are broken so the feed data that is returned contains some null feeds, parsing them causes this exception.

Change this line of code:

```
var matches = _feedDataSource.Feeds.Where((feed) => feed.Title.Equals(title));
```

to :

```
var matches = _feedDataSource.Feeds.Where((feed) => feed != null && feed.Title.Equals(title));
```

This will ignore those empty feeds.